# how to redirect specific http url to https in web config

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

i want to redirect www.abcd.com to https://www.abcd.com , i used below code for that but all other domain under that is also redirected. so how to stop other redirection and perform only above redirection.please help me.

```
 <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">

                 <match url="(.*)"  />   
                 <conditions>
                         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                 </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.abcd.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: Do you want to do that for your whole website on this domain or only for that url ?

Comment: @cahmadzadeh only for that url it must go to the url with https.

Answer (score 0):

Add input in the conditions, It works

```
<rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?abcd.com" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```